# Isometric maps between spaces with different dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, quantum-information

I have the following problem:

Consider complex Euclidean spaces H and H′
such that $dim(H) ⩽ dim(H′)$.
Let ${|v_i⟩}^{k}_{i=1} ⊂ H$ and ${|w_i⟩}^{k}_{i=1} ⊂ H′$ denote orthonormal sets of vectors.

Show that there exists an isometry $V : H → H′$such that $V |v_i⟩ = |w_i⟩$ for all i ∈ {1,. . . , k}.

I know that if the spaces has equal dimension you could find a unitary operator U such that $U|v_i⟩ = |w_i⟩$ for all i.
My question is can we define the the isometry as
$$
V=U+\sum |w_j⟩ 
$$
Where U is a unitary of dimension dim(H) and the sum is of length dim(H')-dim(H)$.

Or maybe something similar?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $V = U + \sum |w_j\rangle$, this does not look like the definition of a linear map to me. You can just take the requirement $V|v_i\rangle = |w_i \rangle $ and extend by linearity. You then have to show that this is an isometry, but that should be straightforward, if you know the $|w_i\rangle$ and $|v_i\rangle$ form orthonormal sets.

Comment: Expand $\{|v_i\rangle\}_i$ and $\{|w_i\rangle\}_i$ to full orthonormal bases of $H$ and $H'$ of sizes $n, n'$ respectively, so $n ⩽ n'$. Then define $V \sum_{i=1}^n a_i|v_i\rangle =  \sum_{i=1}^n a_i|w_i\rangle$